# JMETER-> How do we start 2nd thread group when the 1st thread group is already executing the requests

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

Scenario:
1. I have a login request
2. I have a request for get all activities
3. Now i have a request for create meeting

This will execute one after the other(as i checked the check box in test plan) want to run consecutively

Now scenario 2:
1. login request 
2. Get all activities
3. Update meeting

I want the second scenario to be executed while the first scenario is in progress  or say first scenario reaches the 3rd point i.e. request for create meeting is ready to hit

please help

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/), it can be used for synchronization between Thread Groups so you can kick off requests in 2nd Thread Group by putting something into FIFO queue like it's done in the [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx)

You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Install Plugins Manager Inter Thread Communication]